# Double integration with a little bit difficult interval

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Let $T$ be the area between $x=y^2 + 1$ and $x=2$. Find the value of

$$\int\int_{T} [35xy^2 + 7e^x y^3] dx dy$$

I'll show what I've done: my first step was to find $y=\pm 1$. So, the limits of the integral would be $-1\leq y\leq 1$ and $2\leq x \leq y^2+1$, obtaining
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{2}^{y^2+1}[35xy^2 + 7e^x y^3] dx dy.$$
Integrating with respect to $x$, I got:
$$7 \int_{-1}^{1} [\frac{5}{2}y^6 + 5y^4 + \frac{5}{2}y^2 + y^3 (e^{(y^2+1)}) -10y^2 -e^2y^3] dy$$
I kept on trying several times but I've lost myself in computations, obtaining strange results. Probably, there are just few steps to the correct result, but I can't "view" the idea.

I also foolishly tried to compute the limits of the integral in a second (wrong) way, obtaining $0\leq x\leq 2$ and $ -\sqrt{x-1} \leq y \leq \sqrt{x-1}$, but I didn't go furtherly, because I noticed by myself $0\leq x< 1$ is out of domain with respect to $y$.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Note that the domain of integration is symmetric with respect to the line $y=0$, hence your integral is just
$$\iint_{T} [35xy^2 + 7e^x y^3] dx dy=\iint_{T} [35xy^2] dx dy=
2\cdot 35\int_{y=0}^1 y^2\left(\int_{x=y^2+1}^{2}x\, dx\right) dy$$
because $7e^x y^3$ is an odd function in the variable $y$ and $35xy^2$ is an even one.

Comment: Too bad the tick works on 1 profile. I am a novice of this site and i found useful all the answers. Thanks again! Forgive my repeatitiveness (not in my intentions to violate any rule of the site :) )

Answer (score 0):

Note that your method is correct. The issue is with setting the limits for $x$, which must be $y^2+1\le x\le 2$. You calculated the inner definite integral correctly (just reverse the signs due to the reversed limits). And then, as Robert Z noted, note that $y^3e^{y^2+1}, e^2y^3$ are odd, hence their integrals at $[-1,1]$ are $0$. The rest are polynomial, easy to integrate and find the final answer $16$.

Comment: Thanks for finding my answer useful. However, I think the credit should still go to @Robert Z, who delicately hinted to the issue (notice the limits of inner integral of his answer) and noted the odd integrant functions. So you should accept his answer. Regards.

Comment: Too bad the tick works on 1 profile. I am a novice of this site and i found useful all the answers. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. Don't worry, I had fun solving the integral and helping.